# Laravel getting data from another table with Auth::user()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I am relatively new to Laravel.

I have 2 different tables. `roles` and `users`.

I want to be able to do `Auth::user()->role->perms` to get the permissions for the user role.

In my `User.php` I have the following

```php
public function role(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Role::class, 'role');
    }
```

In my `Role.php` I have the following

```php
public function users() {
        return $this->HasMany(User::class);
    }
```

Here is my `create_users_table.php`

```php
Schema::connection('panel')->create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('steam64');
            $table->string('steamName');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('role')->default('user');
            $table->rememberToken();
        });
```

Here is my `create_roles_table.php`

```php
Schema::connection('panel')->create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('role');
            $table->json('perms')->default('{"full_perms":0, "some_other_perms":0}');
            $table->integer('immunity')->default(10);
        });
```

When I use `{{Auth::user()->role->perms}}`, I get the following error `Trying to get property 'perms' of non-object`.

Hope this is enough information. If not, I can provide additional information.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... perhaps the field `role` should be `role_id` so it can hold the id of the Role to keep this normalized? also if you have an attribute with the name `role` then the model will give you that attribute named `role` before it would check for the relationship named `role` ... so don't name a relationship the same name as a field if you want to be able to access both via the dynamic property

Comment: @lagbox Changing `role` in to `role_id` made it work. Thanks for the help!

Comment: if you want to add an answer of how you solved it in a little detail to help someone else please feel free

Answer (score 0):

So you need to define user_id on roles table and it would be nice to define what will happen with the role when user will be deleted.

create_roles_table.php

```
 Schema::connection('panel')->create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('role');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->json('perms')->default('{"full_perms":0, "some_other_perms":0}');
            $table->integer('immunity')->default(10);
        });
```

Also delete $table->string('role')->default('user'); from user table, you do not need that.

Comment: I do not believe this answers the question

Answer (score 0):

in users table role column cannot be string it must be id of role table and it should be unsigned